# Accidentally deleted many system folders and files

Tags: system, restore

I have typed the following command.

```
cd /var/www/html/dev.sportsdirect.bg
rm -r /*
```

Then i notcied that the home folder and many others are deleted. How can i restore that. Right now i have working SSH connection to the server and all files under /var/www/html/ are not deleted for my luck.

Whatever command i type i get this error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory
```

Can you please tell me how can i restore my system ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be careful when you use rm. For future reference, you should have used `./*` or just `*` to delete the contents of the current directory instead of `/*` because `/` is the top level directory and `./` is the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Quite honestly - reinstallation will be probably your easiest and quickest option. You can do that without re-formatting partitions, which may prevent your current data (or what's left of it)

For the beginning anyway use LiveCD maybe and backup whatever's left from your important stuff.

You can try recovery mode and run some actions, maybe apt-get reinstall will help you - but if you're not really sure what's been exactly removed, that may not be your easiest solution.

Comment: What is this LiveCD and how can i backup all files under /var/www/ and how can i backup all my mysql databases ?

Comment: That may help for LiveCD:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD. It refers to the older version, but generally it's the same story. Basically you have to prepare a new Ubuntu CD (or actually USB, whichever you prefer) - and start it in live mode, without reinstalling the system.

Comment: As for backup - well... tar/gzip may help you. For MySQL - the best would be to get familiar with this database a bit, but anyway - for start backup of your databases files (/var/lib/mysql I guess?) with tar/gzip should be enough - just make sure you either stop the database or apply read lock - to make sure your backup is consistent.  (if your mysql installation is still fine after all that removal - you can use mysqldump - but I guess that in your situation archiving of the db directory will be a better solution)  - just make sure you back it up to some safe location.

Comment: I got this error:
`error: file 'grub/e386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
Entering rescue mode...` What i have to do from here ?

Comment: Again, use rather LiveCD - boot your system from it and do your backups and then reinstall. And quite honestly - no offence - if you're not sure what to do with it, leave it to someone who knows the stuff. Otherwise you will probably spend a good while trying to fix it and you still risk more data loss.

Comment: My linux is ubuntu server 14.04 do i have to load a desktop version to do my backups ?

Comment: At this stage - for backups it doesn't really matter. But for reinstallation use rather the version you have currently.

Comment: I have succeed to backup all files which i need. But when i go and try to open /var/lib/mysql i get error for not having permissions to see that folder. Can you give me any advice what i can do ?

Comment: You have to do that as privileged user (root should do)

Comment: Can you give me the exact command that i can use to create tar.gzip archive of that folder at my desktop ? Thank you so much for helping me!

Comment: tar cvzf your_archive.tgz your_directory_to_backup   - something like that should work.     c is for create, v - verbose, z - gzip, f - archive file to create, which takes the name of your choice with .tgz suffix (you can use .tar.gz as well - it doesn't really matter - but helps indicating what actual file you're dealing with)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31043/discussion-between-tony-stark-and-jacek).

Comment: later for restore you should use something like that:  tar xvzf your_archive.tgz  (be careful again where you extract it). x  is for extract there. Anyway - I'd recommend man tar and man gzip - that may help you in the future. These are quite popular archiving tools.

Comment: What do you think about installing the system on other hard drive, not on the one i have used for now ?

Comment: Up to you - if you want a new installation on another disk, sure, why not.

Comment: This will give me access when the system is installed to the old hard drive so i can go there and view files ?

Comment: If you have that spare disk drive - that may be a good option, indeed. And then copy your stuff from the old disk.

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu server on the another drive, but i can not open my old one. It seems not installed. Can you give me any advice ?

Comment: Did you mount the old disk properly?

Comment: I succeeded to create and a backup for /var/lib/mysql hoping there will be all the data from my mysql server. So for the next step when i already have backup for the mysql server and the other files i need i think to create a new fresh install of ubuntu server. But i have a question, how can i import the extracted files from the mysql server ? Do i have to copy and paste them on the same location in the new installed ubuntu server ? Thanks

Comment: Copy /var/lib/mysql with databases to the new server - that should be more or less all. It might be good actually also if you had your original mysql config file (my.cnf I think) - also copied from the old server - but if it's gone you can create a new one or even try to start mysql on defaults.